# ValueError : Length of values does not match length index

Tags: python, pandas, list, for-loop

```py
import pandas as pd
dict1 = {'id_game': [112, 113, 114], 'game_name' : ['x','z','y'],'id_category':[1,2,3], 'id_players':[[588,589,590],[589],[588,589]]}
dict2 = {'id_player': [588, 589, 590],'player_name' : ['fff','aaa','ccc'] ,'indication':['mmm x ggg sdg y', 'uuu x fdb y kfnkjq z', 'fffre x']}
game_df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
player_df = pd.DataFrame(dict2)
```

Here is my sample of the data that I have, I am looking to find a solution for getting a column contain categories_id in the second dataframe `game_df` based on  relation between `game_df['id_players']` and `player_df['id_player']` or `game_df['game_name']` and `drug_df['indication']`

In the following script i used `game_name` and `indication` values :

```py
new_list = []
for i in range(len(game_df)):
    for j in range(len(player_df)):
        if game_df['game_name'][i] in player_df['indication'][j]:
            new_list.append(game_df['id_category'][i])
            print(new_list)
            
player_df['categories_id'] = new_list
```

ERROR :

```
--> 747         raise ValueError(
    748             "Length of values "
    749             f"({len(data)}) "

ValueError: Length of values (6) does not match length of index (3)
```

Comment: The error message is clear. Your dataframe length is 3 and your list length is 6. You are exceeding df index limit

Comment: That's why I asked my question, I understood the error, but I did not find a solution to solve it

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be fixed by adding `break` after `print(new_list)`, with
the same indentation.

```py
...
if game_df['game_name'][i] in player_df['indication'][j]:
    new_list.append(game_df['id_category'][i])
    print(new_list)
    break
```

---

That being said, iterating over dataframes is highly discouraged because it's slow and gets unwieldy very quickly. The canonical way to approach problems like this would be to `merge` the dataframes on the `id_player(s)`, i.e., explode the ids in `id_players` into individual rows,

```py
>>> game_df = game_df.explode("id_players").rename(columns={"id_players": "id_player"})
>>> game_df
   id_game game_name  id_category id_player
0      112         x            1       588
0      112         x            1       589
0      112         x            1       590
1      113         z            2       589
2      114         y            3       588
2      114         y            3       589
```

so you can `.merge` it with the `game_df`,

```py
>>> df = game_df.merge(player_df, on="id_player")
>>> df
   id_game game_name  id_category id_player player_name            indication
0      112         x            1       588         fff       mmm x ggg sdg y
1      114         y            3       588         fff       mmm x ggg sdg y
2      112         x            1       589         aaa  uuu x fdb y kfnkjq z
3      113         z            2       589         aaa  uuu x fdb y kfnkjq z
4      114         y            3       589         aaa  uuu x fdb y kfnkjq z
5      112         x            1       590         ccc               fffre x
```

That will make analyses rather straightforward, like checking if the `game_name` is in the `indication` becomes

```py
df.apply(lambda row: row.game_name in row.indication, axis=1)
```

though it returns True for all of them, so I'm not sure if that's actually what you want.

Comment: thank you @fsimonjetz for your answer, my target is player_df, I want to keep the column `player_df['id_player']` as the primary key and add a column contains a list of categories_id